# Set SelectedItem on a combobox bound to datasource

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource, selecteditem

```
List<Customer> _customers = getCustomers().ToList();
BindingSource bsCustomers = new BindingSource();
bsCustomers.DataSource = _customers;
comboBox.DataSource = bsCustomers.DataSource;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox.ValueMember = "id";
```

Now how do I set the combobox's Item to something other than the first in the list?
Tried
comboBox.SelectedItem = someCustomer;
...and lots of other stuff but no luck so far...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = "valueToSelect";
```

or

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = n;
```

or

```
comboBox.Items[n].Selected = true;
```

Comment: comboBox.Items[n].Selected = true; doesnt work for me (might be a CF issue) but SelectedValue does, I tried it before but with the wrong value. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to note that for me to get this to work I had to specify the field that was the value member, not just the object. So in the case of customers above, I had to use `comboBox.SelectedValue = customerToSelect.id`.

Answer (score 2):

Your binding code is not complete. Try this:

```
BindingSource bsCustomers = new BindingSource();
bsCustomers.DataSource = _customers;

comboBox.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", bsCustomers, "id", true));
comboBox.DataSource = bsCustomers;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox.ValueMember = "id";
```

---

In most cases you can accomplish this task in the designer, instead of doing it in code.

Start by adding a data source in the "Data Sources" window in Visual Studio. Open it from menu *View > Other Windows > Data Sources*. Add an Object data source of `Customer` type. In the Data Sources you will see the customer's properties. Through a right click on the properties you can change the default control associated to it.

Now you can simply drag a property from the Data Sources window to you form. Visual Studio automatically adds A `BindingSource` and a `BindingNavigator` component to your form when you drop the first control. The `BindingNavigator` is optional and you can safely remove it, if you don't need it. Visual Studio also does all the wire-up. You can tweak it through the properties window. Sometimes this is required for combo boxes.

There's only one thing left to do in your code: Assign an actual data source to the binding source:

```
customerBindingSource.DataSource = _customers;
```

Comment: With that it crasches on comboBox.ValueMember = "id"; for some reason?

Comment: I suggest you to add the `BindingSource` as a component to your form in the designer (see `Data` section of the `Toolbox`). Then you can set all these properties through the properties window. It is even easier, if you start by defining an object data source in the `Data Sources` window in VS. Then you can simply drag the fields from this window to your form and the binding-wire-up is done automatically. A `BindingSource` and a `BindingNavigator` are inserted automatically, if you do so. Then, you can safely remove the `BindingNavigator` if you do not need it.

Comment: which property or object represent the bound selected item? isn't bsCustomers a list and it has multiple "id"

Comment: The data source is a `List<Customer>` and `Customer` has `id` and `name`  properties. The `Customer.id` is bound to the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
bsCustomers.Position = comboBox.Items.IndexOf(targetCustomer);
```