# Combobox with datasource not allowing SelectedIndex to be set

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public static readonly List<string> EdgeDetail =
   new List<string>() { "", "BC - Beaded Cove", "BD - Beaded", "CF - Chamfer", "CT - Coastal", "CV - Cove", "DR - Double Radius", "SQ - Square", "SB - Step Bevel", "TBD - To Be Determined", "None - No Edge Detail"};

ComboBox extraText = new ComboBox();

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = EdgeDetail;
extraText.DataSource = bs;
extraText.SelectedIndex = 3;  // This causes exception
```

I set a ComboBox's datasource to a list of strings using an intermediary Binding Source (same results without the BindingSource).  Then I try to pick an index based on something I've saved.  The example above causes the following exception:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
> Parameter name: SelectedIndex

I've tried SelectedText, SelectedValue, and finally decided to show you the simplest which is just setting SelectedIndex to a hard-coded value (3) which should display "CF - Chamfer".  In the watch window I've looked at the datasource of the combobox and it shows a count of 11 and all 11 values right at the line setting SelectedIndex.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015942/set-selecteditem-on-a-combobox-bound-to-datasource

Comment: Yes, but when you inspect the combo property `Created`, it says `false`. A combo added to the form (e.g. using the designer) is created and initialized. This suggested me there was something else missing here.

Comment: Data binding is lazy, nothing happens until the control is visible.  It is not obvious from the snippet why that's not the case, but a workaround is `bs.Position = 3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new combo object from scratch rather than using one that's already in the form. Just need to add it to the Controls on that form: `this.Controls.Add(extraText);`. So when the form is loaded, its controls are created and initialised.

```cs
ComboBox extraText = new ComboBox();
this.Controls.Add(extraText);
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = EdgeDetail;
extraText.DataSource = bs;
extraText.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

The reason why you don't need to add this line for a combo that was added using Visual Studio Designer is because the Designer automatically generate a partial class in `Form1.Designer.cs` which contains `InitializeComponent()` including `this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);`.

Comment: Thank you derloopkat!  It was that simple, adding the control right after creating it, instead of at the end of configuring it.